# Batch Operations API V3 - blank response

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Here is a sample of a bacth operation request:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<IntuitBatchRequest xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" >
   <BatchItem  operation="sparse" bId="bid1">
    <Invoice>
       <Id>183</Id>
       <SyncToken>4</SyncToken>
       <SalesTermRef>5</SalesTermRef>
    </Invoice>           
   </BatchItem>
</IntuitBatchRequest>
```

I get a blank response and the invoice is not updated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-11-26T09:45:12.812-08:00"/>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I have found what was causing the issue.

In the request I was using the tag BatchItem because this is the sample provided in the documentation, and there is in the text reference to it.

Use the tag BatchItemRequest instead, and all is fine.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I will get it corrected.